# .style.webkitTransform not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

The following code is working perfectly in Safari to rotate a prism on scroll, but not working in other browsers, like Chrome. I think the problem has to do with the .style.webkitTransform, but I cannot figure out a fix and I've tried everything. PLease help. I'm still learning

Here's a link to the site http://katielabarta.com/projects.html

```
window.onscroll = function() {
var lower = document.getElementById("lower");
var scroll_length = 230;  // for full scroll use 1080 
var top = document.body.scrollTop;
 if (top < scroll_length) {
lower.style.webkitTransform = "translateZ(-30px) rotateX(" + top / scroll_length*230 + "deg)";
lower.style.msTransform = "translateZ(-30px) rotateX(" + top / scroll_length*230 + "deg)";
lower.style.transform = "translateZ(-30px) rotateX(" + top / scroll_length*230 + "deg)";
} else {
lower.style.webkitTransform = "translateZ(-30px) rotateX(0deg)";
lower.style.msTransform = "translateZ(-30px) rotateX(0deg)";
lower.style.transform = "translateZ(-30px) rotateX(0deg)";
}
};
```

Comment: Might want to wrap those calculations in parentheses. You may also want to remove those extra `webkitTransform` and `msTransform` vendor-prefixes, since [recent versions of those browsers support the `transform` property without them](https://caniuse.com/#search=transform).

Comment: I added those extra things as part of the process of fixing this problem, I originally didn't have them. I'll try parentheses though thank you

Comment: I think that you need also use 'perspective'.For Example 

    transform= 'perspective(500px) translateZ(200px);'

Comment: Where would I add that? @СергейПетрашко

Comment: I hope that i can help you. For example : lower.style.transform = "perspective(500px) ranslateZ(-30px) rotateX(0deg)"; And last version of chrome use only transform without 'webkit'.

Comment: I tried that but it did not help it rotate unfortunately. I may be doing it wrong, but thank you so much for trying @СергейПетрашко